# IRQ numbers in Output of lspci

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling, pci, irq

For one of my pci device, output of lspci -vvv says pin A routed to 19. but output of lspci -b -vvv gives 255. All the pci devices gives irq 255 in lspci -b -vvv, while for lspci -vvv it gives different numbers. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: *-b     Bus-centric  view. Show all IRQ numbers and addresses as seen by the cards on the PCI bus instead of as seen by the kernel.* So, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am asking that it is ok that all devices show irq 255 in bus centric view.

Comment: PCI interrupts are out-of-band signals, so what do you expect to see?

Comment: @CL I guess it also depends on HW architecture (PIC + PIR) used on certain platform. I just run the above on x86 and got the numbers kinda ISA range, and not 255.

Comment: When we add -b in lspci it gives us the irq no which seen from the device. where in actual lspci output it is virtual irq number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert -b in lspci command it will gives you the interrupt number seen by the device. So this interrupt number will be hardware interrupt number. Without -b, it will give you virtual interrupt number. So these both number will be different.